# Looping through json encoded object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am simply trying to loop through this in javascript from encoding it in php then bringing it through ajax.

```
[{"approved":false,"response":"Not working."}]
```

When logging the ResultJSON var below the data back through my ajax call, it looks like that above in the console.

This is the code I am using to loop with. When logging the key, I get back a bunch of letters. I want to get the key of approved and the value of false along with the response key and value.

```
ResultJSON = data;
console.log(ResultJSON);
for (var key in ResultJSON) {
  if (ResultJSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     console.log(ResultJSON[key]);
  }
}
```

As I try 0, 1, 2 from what you guys suggest.. It gives me the next letter in the log. So data[1] would give me back a `{` and data[2] a `"`.

EDIT:

This is how I build my encoded object through php.

```
$build = array();
$buildTwo = array();
$object = new stdClass();
$build["approved"] = $approved;
$build["response"] = $response_reason_text;
$buildTwo[] = $build;
echo json_encode($buildTwo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the object you are trying to iterate over is a single element in an array?  (Notice the []s around the {}s).

Try

```
ResultJSON = data[0];
```

Edit - based on your comments about trying multiple indicies and them not working, how are you making your call to get your data?  Are you indicating that you are expecting JSON (or using jQuery.getJSON())?

2nd Edit - I see the php code now, but what about the ajax call?

Comment: I am doing an ajax call to a php file that brings me back only a json type of data. I have two values that I need which are $response and $approved. I then want to loop through those values on the front end once the ajax call is done.

Comment: I managed to figure this out. I was missing the json call for the dataType. Thanks Matt!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, not a problem at all, just thought I'd ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your json is wrapped, probably something to do with your php code, but you can get your example to work with

```
ResultJSON = data[0];
console.log(ResultJSON);
for (var key in ResultJSON) {
    if (ResultJSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(ResultJSON[key]);
    }
}
```